# Episode of "The Familiar of Zero" where Saito feeds Tabitha's dragon again

Tags: anime, episode-identification, dragons

I've forgotten which episode of *The Familiar of Zero* Saito feeds Tabitha's dragon again in. Because it's been a long since I last watched it, and I don't remember the scene.

Answer (score 1):

Might this be the fifth episode of season 3, **"[The Alluring Women's Bath](https://thefamiliarofzero.fandom.com/wiki/The_Alluring_Women%27s_Bath)"** (2008)...?

[This page](https://www.themoviedb.org/tv/35753-zero-no-tsukaima/season/3/episode/10?language=pt-PT) mentions a scene where Saito is saved by Tabitha as a favour for him feeding her dragon earlier in the same episode.

> After the events of the last episode, Saito was forced, in his boxers, to read aloud and sign a pledge admitting that he took advantage of Tiffania in the infirmary. However, he refuses to sign it, insisting that it was she who asked him, and leaves. Upon seeing the shack where Professor Colbert kept his books and other materials, he entered and sadly remembered the teacher's wish to someday visit Saito's world. He apparently starts to doze off, but wakes up after hitting his head on the table. His attention then turns to the piles of gifts being left for Guiche and Reynald, and inquires as to their meaning, in which case, Reynald explains that gifts from the ladies are becoming more common after the fight with the Air Dragon Knights from the previous episode. With love seemingly in the air, Saito remembers the fight with Louise and becomes rather depressed. Upon seeing this, Guiche, Malicorne, and Reynald grow determined to cheer him up. A newcomer in the Knights of Ondine, Gimli, comes up with an idea, and they set about to digging a hole to the women's bathhouse, where they use magic to create a small peephole, bringing Saito along to join them. In the bath, Tiffania explains to Louise that it was she who asked Saito to touch her breasts. This leaves Louise a bit upset over her treatment of him, realizing that she didn't even bother to listen, and fears that he may not come back. However, when Tiffania makes the statement that the two are lovers, Louise immediately shoots that notion down. Saito yells for them to stop peeking at her, and his loud voice gathers the attention of Tabitha, who speaks up. The hole is noticed, and their fun is over. They manage to escape, but are found and swiftly punished by the girls. **Saito, however, is saved by Tabitha (as a favor for him feeding her dragon earlier in the episode).** When Montmorency comes into the dining hall looking for Guiche, Tabitha hides Saito in a rather provocative manner--by pressing her naked body up against him. When word that Guiche has been found, she heads off, but the sound of whispers gains Tabitha's attention, and she soon passes out from fear of ghosts. The dolls appear and start dancing, and Saito is reminded of the party from the first season. Louise shows up, explaining the nature of the dolls' appearance. She has him admit to being with the others who were peeking, but he explains that he was deceived, half expecting her not to believe him. She believes him, though, and they embrace. However, the embrace comes to an abrupt end when Tabitha wakes up for a brief moment, and once again, Louise gets the wrong idea. He ends up in the same position as in the beginning, only this time the pledge is for him never to touch breasts smaller than Louise's (or anyone else, for that matter). In protest, Siesta grabs Saito's hand and rests it on her breast, and in a rage, Louise blows him up.